# ASP.NET MVC POST Method Not Receiving JSON Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a mobile app that posts to my ASP.NET MVC 4 `HttpPost` method and every time it receives data, it's not receiving the correct data.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public void NewItems(Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> newItemsDictionary) 
{
}
```

I have my RouteConfig setup as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "API", action = "Index" }
        );
```

The mobile app is posting to the URL https://api.test.com/NewItems and the parameters are a JSON encoded dictionary with one key, `newItems` and the value is an array of dictionaries (`[["user": "testUser1", "itemNumber": "123-45678"], ["user": "testUser2", "itemNumber": "456-7890"]]`)

I have a try/catch block setup inside the POST method to catch any errors. When the method is posted to, it goes into the catch block and tells me that the "**newItem**" key doesn't exist within the `newItemsDictionary` parameter. The keys that do exist in the parameter are: `action` and `controller`. The action and controller keys do not contain any values.

Why is this happening and what should I change to receive the correct data?

Comment: Your parameter for NewItems is seriously confusing. You need to match the javascript object structure with the parmater then you can call json.stringify on the object to serialize to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the request model binding works with a Dictionary, so, if you are expecting a Dictionary, you will be probably dealing with the request itself.

You should change the dictionary into a ViewModel or something you could use. For IE:

```
public class UserItemViewModel 
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And then, you post a list of UserItemViewModel.

Comment: OP states the parameters are ([["user": "testUser1", "itemNumber": "123-45678"], ["user": "testUser2", "itemNumber": "456-7890"]]) which would be the correct format to pass the parameter via json.

Comment: OP could try like this `NewItems(List<UserItemViewModel> newItems)`, I could not say for sure without testing.

Comment: I cannot use a view model. The data is not coming in via any kind of web application. It is being posted by a mobile application.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The json data you pass into the action will be parsed by the Model Binder into a UserItemViewModel.

Comment: Do I need to do anything with the ```newItems``` key that's coming in from the data being posted?

Comment: @bkhosh2 post it simply as an array of UserItemViewModel. [ {"user": "testUser1", "itemNumber": "123-45678" }, {"user": "testUser2", "itemNumber": "456-7890" }]

Comment: Thanks for your help Federico!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to wait for a list of `Dictionary` objects that needs to be dealt with in an error-prone way.

It would be much better if you map the request to a `strongly typed` object.

```
public class ItemsViewModel 
{
    public string user;
    public string itemNumber;
}
```

Then your Api Method would Look as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public void NewItems(List<ItemsViewModel> newItems) 
{
     foreach(var item in newItems){
         item.user... // And so on.
     }
}
```